# How to pause game in Unity when the Steam Overlay is called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steam

I am developing a game in Unity for the steam platform. I want to know how to pause the game when the Steam Overlay is called. I tried several things but nothing worked.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's a good question seeking general approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Steamworks API has a function inside the `ISteamUtils` interface called `IsOverlayEnabled` that you can call to check if the Steam Overlay is currently active. By checking this function periodically you could call up your pause screen when necessary.

> ### IsOverlayEnabled
>
> `bool IsOverlayEnabled();`
>
> Checks if the Steam Overlay is running & the user can access it.
>
> The overlay process could take a few seconds to start & hook the game
> process, so this function will initially return false while the
> overlay is loading.
>
> **Returns:** bool

https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamUtils#IsOverlayEnabled

Comment: This is incorrect. This just checks if the overlay system is enabled and can be shown.

Answer (score 4):

1 make sure you are using:

```
using SteamWorks
```

2Create a Callback

```
protected Callback<GameOverlayActivated_t> overlayIsOn;
```

3 At start check if Steam manager is initialized

```
 if (!SteamManager.Initialized)
        {
            return;
        }
```

4 make a funtion that takes the callback

```
void PauseGameIfSteamOverlayOn(GameOverlayActivated_t callback)
    {
        if (canPause)
        {
            // PAUSE GAME
        }
    }
```

5 create the callback variable and add the funtion

```
 overlayIsOn = Callback<GameOverlayActivated_t>.Create(PauseGameIfSteamOverlayOn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic usage of the Steam bool isOverlayEnabled() function.  Note download and install Steamworks.Net package to your Unity project required first.  Untested, but inheriting Monobehavior likely not needed...

```
using Steamworks;

public class DemoClass : Monobehaviour {

    if(SteamUtils.IsOverlayEnabled()) {
        // pause...
    }
}
```